# Why is the result of this GLSL shader asymetric when rendering with stereo "Side-By-Side"?

Tags: game-engine, shaders

I am trying to achieve an inverse lens ditortion for the Oculus Rift during Side-By-Side stereo in the game engine. I am using a custom Filter2D with this GLSL shader.

The distortion can be achieved as described [here](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~mccrae/projects/firebox/). Another fragment shader for that cause can be found in the [OpenHMD examples](https://github.com/OpenHMD/OpenHMD/blob/master/examples/opengl/shaders/test1.frag.glsl).

The distortion looks good without stereo, but is asymmetric when I render it with Side-By-Side. For other stereo options, the output is not correct, but symmetric. Where is the problem here?

```
uniform sampler2D bgl_RenderedTexture;

const vec4 kappa = vec4(1.0,1.7,0.7,15.0);

uniform float screen_width;
uniform float screen_height;

const float scaleFactor = 0.9;

const vec2 leftCenter = vec2(0.25, 0.5);
const vec2 rightCenter = vec2(0.75, 0.5);

// Scales input texture coordinates for distortion.
vec2 hmdWarp(vec2 LensCenter, vec2 texCoord, vec2 Scale, vec2 ScaleIn) {
    vec2 theta = (texCoord - LensCenter) * ScaleIn; 
    float rSq = theta.x * theta.x + theta.y * theta.y;
    vec2 rvector = theta * (kappa.x + kappa.y * rSq + kappa.z * rSq * rSq + kappa.w * rSq * rSq * rSq);
    vec2 tc = LensCenter + Scale * rvector;
    return tc;
}

bool validate(vec2 tc, int left_eye) {
    //keep within bounds of texture 
    if ((left_eye == 1 && (tc.x < 0.0 || tc.x > 0.5)) ||   
        (left_eye == 0 && (tc.x < 0.5 || tc.x > 1.0)) ||
        tc.y < 0.0 || tc.y > 1.0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void main() {
    vec2 screen = vec2(screen_width, screen_height);

    float as = float(screen.x / 2.0) / float(screen.y);
    vec2 Scale = vec2(0.5, as);
    vec2 ScaleIn = vec2(2.0 * scaleFactor, 1.0 / as * scaleFactor);

    vec2 texCoord = gl_TexCoord[0].st;

    vec2 tc = vec2(0);
    vec4 color = vec4(0);

    if (texCoord.x < 0.5) {
        tc = hmdWarp(leftCenter, texCoord, Scale, ScaleIn );
        color = texture2D(bgl_RenderedTexture, tc);
        if (!validate(tc, 1))
            color = vec4(0);
    } else {
        tc = hmdWarp(rightCenter, texCoord, Scale, ScaleIn);
        color = texture2D(bgl_RenderedTexture, tc);
        if (!validate(tc, 0))
            color = vec4(0);
    }   
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

These are my [render results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nku7M.png).

**First Image:** Rendered with Above-Below, the result is at least symmetric.

**Second Image:** Rendered with no stereo, looking good, but unusable for the glasses.

**Third Image:** Asymmetric Side-By-Side rendering cropped.

**Fourth Image:** Aysmmetric Side-By-Side rendering without crop (validate function commented out)

The relevant stereo code is in [RAS_OpenGLRasterizer.cpp](https://gitorious.org/blenderprojects/blender/blobs/master/blender/source/gameengine/Rasterizer/RAS_OpenGLRasterizer/RAS_OpenGLRasterizer.cpp#line513), but I couldn't find the cause of the asymmetry.

**Edit:** A blend file with this issue can be downloaded [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0bLtNyAhxgoZlgycFN4NHRNLTQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you provide a .blend file? I'm not sure how to hook up a GLSL post-processing filter to the game engine's final output. Without looking at it, it's hard to say if your input coordinates are off, or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moguri [answered my question](http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?298241-Just-one-last-step-to-get-Oculus-Rift-working-fully-in-BGE) on the forums by posting [this patch](http://www.pasteall.org/43512/diff) that fixes the Filter 2D issue in Blender.

The patch:

```
diff --git blender/source/gameengine/Rasterizer/RAS_2DFilterManager.cpp blender/source/gameengine/Rasterizer/RAS_2DFilterManager.cpp index 79ce853..1781852 100644
--- blender/source/gameengine/Rasterizer/RAS_2DFilterManager.cpp
+++ blender/source/gameengine/Rasterizer/RAS_2DFilterManager.cpp @@ -429,6 +429,9 @@ void RAS_2DFilterManager::RenderFilters(RAS_ICanvas* canvas)
        glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0);
        canvas->SetViewPort(0, 0, rect_width-1, rect_height-1);  
+       RAS_Rect scissor_rect = canvas->GetDisplayArea();
+       glScissor(scissor_rect.GetLeft()+viewport[0], scissor_rect.GetBottom()+viewport[1], scissor_rect.GetWidth()+1, scissor_rect.GetHeight()+1);
+
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        // in case the previous material was wire
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
```

Note: This patch is already included in the trunk, verified at 08/25/2013

Comment: Please consider putting the solution here since [link-only questions are not considered good](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: @lubosz Thanks for your wrapper for the oculus rift. How should the wrapper installed in blender without distutils?